# Piping Observables and Returning a Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Why does the code below return a `promise` that contains an `observable`?

```
const queryApi = (request: AxiosRequestConfig): Observable<ParsedData> => {
  return new Observable(observer => {
      axios(request).then(response => {
          observer.next(response);
          observer.complete();
      }).catch(error => {
          observer.error(error);
      })
  }).pipe(map(value => {
      const parser = new Parser(name);
      const response = value as AxiosResponse;
      return parser.parse(response.data);
  }));
}

const sourcePromise: Promise<ParsedData> = queryApi(request, 1).toPromise();
await sourcePromise.then(source$ => {
    source$.subscribe((value: ParsedData) => console.log(JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)));
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I was expecting the code to:

1. Query an API with `axios`
2. Create an observable using the value resolved by `axios`
3. Pipe that observable to a `map` operator that returns an `observable`
4. Convert return `observable` to `promise`
5. Resolve `promise` to expose data.

Comment: i tihnk it might have something to do with not being completed

but if you want to get a promise anyway why not jsut return a promise in the first place

Comment: I haven't used typescript, but it looks like you aren't calling the promise, just referencing it. `sourcePromise.then` -> `sourcePromise().then`

Comment: Are you saying that `parser.parse` returns an observable?

Comment: Why are you using observables at all here? You're turning a promise into an observable, then turning that back into a promise. Just use promises directly to make your code much simpler.

Comment: Where exactly in that code does it "*return a promise that contains an observable*"?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Using rxjs 6
// This should solve your problem.

import axios from 'axios';
import {from} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

const queryApi = request => from(axios(request)).pipe(map(res => res.data));

//Make sure to subscribe to the observable
```